# Fallout 4 on vita without a ps4

Tags: fallout-4

Okay I know it's stupid. I have a psvita and I got pretty far in fallout on vita before my neighbor sold his ps4
I have saved data on my psn account so is there any way I can play fallout 4 on vita without a ps4. Mods whatever I'll do it

Comment: Buy a PS4.  How, exactly, are you supposed to make a PS4 game run on your Vita without that?

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

The only way to play Fallout 4 on the Vita is through the PS4's Remote Play feature.  If you no longer have access to a PS4, you're missing the core infrastructure required to make this work.  No PS4 = No Fallout 4.

Answer (score 1):

Remote control is not the same as independent play on Vita. Many people wish at least PS2 games on Vita or GTA4 but Fallout... Vita is too weak for F4, even for F3 and moreover for market and developers this console is "nearly dead". So you should come for new PS4.